# Angular Form Validation Across Several States/Views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

Bit of a broad question however I'm sure someone can offer me some sound advice!

I am currently developing a form which is presented to a user over several views/states. A user fills out the first section, clicks 'next', state changes and the next part of the form appears etc...

When the user goes to submit the form on the last state and they have made some mistakes in the first or second state, would it be possible to have them redirected to the sate in which they made the error, and focus on that field?

I ask simply because I will have to implement this at some point, and do not want to go forward as planned in case this is not possible using several different states to present the form.

Each state shares the same object using a service, which is used to hold the inputted data.

Any advice would be much appreciated as always.

Comment: Just to clarify; I'm not asking anyone to post the code necessary to achieve this. Just looking for some thoughts and opinions on whether or not this is possible.

Comment: That's completely possible, especially if the form is a single model across states.